# Rejoin words breaked by hyphen and double newline characters

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have converted some PDF files to text by Calibre. Sample text as below:

```
The booming population, coupled with a development strategy pre-

mised on high levels of investment, meant that an increasingly large pop-

ulation would be condemned indefinitely to living standards barely above

subsistence level.
```

I just want to combine words "premised" and "population", the pattern should be "-\n\n". But I can't replace the words by `perl -p -e 's/-\n\n//` or `tr -d '\-\n\n'` in the case where two newline characters follow the hyphen character. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `perl -0pe 's/-\n\n//g'`

Comment: That works. Than you.

Comment: @cuonglm, may as well post it as an answer.  I just came across this in the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0):

cuonglm provided an [answer in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294559/rejoin-words-breaked-by-hyphen-and-double-newline-characters#comment516477_294559) that appears to work:

```
perl -0pe 's/-\n\n//g'
```